# Apache config works for www.domain.com but not domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2

My Apache virtual host configuration only works for `www.domain.com` but not `domain.com`. Can you tell me why?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stable/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/stable/php-fcgi-starter .php
    </Directory>

    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somewhere else in your Apache configuration there is another  or ServerName/ServerAlias for 'domain.com'?

Comment: I did a grep on "domain.com" but found nothing wierd in either /etc/ or /var/.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't really any other option but a standard site was defined which was overriding my options. Once I removed it all is well.

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Make sure to restart apache as well...

Answer (score 0):

Have you got host entries setup for www.domain.com but not domain.com ? As it sounds like its not resolving as your apache configuration looks good. Can you ping each address and ensure its going to the correct location?

Comment: When I visit domain.com I get to the standard Apache index file in /var/www/index.html... But www.domain.com points to /var/www/stable/index.php

Answer (score 0):

replace `ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com` with `ServerAlias domain.com`. do `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` have the same ip address/ips that are configured for this host?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, are you sure your DNS answers the same for domain.com and www.domain.com?
To make sure it is the case, a simple check might help:

```
nslookup domain.com
nslookup www.domain.com
```

I've been sometimes struggling for nothing since the two A records would not return the same thing. If or once they are pointing on the same IP then Apache conf can be tuned but this is what I use and it works:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Don't forget to reload Apache (no need to restart it completely and disconnect clients):

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

(or similar)

Good luck!

Comment: They return exactly the same on nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified `NameVirtualHost *:80`?

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using